# spring batch : stop writer when reader return null

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, spring-batch

I'm working with spring batch 4 (annotation) and have a job with one step which reads an XML file and write to a text file. I used a custom reader and a simple flat writer (spring batch reference), before reading XML. I checked if this XML is a file, and if so I process the transformation from XML to text. But if the file is not valid I return `null` in the reader.

The problem is that when I return `null` in the reader, the writer is still working and puts an empty file into the output folder. What is the solution?

```
@Bean public FlatFileItemWriter itemWriter() {
    return  
        new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Foo>()
            .name("itemWriter")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("target/test-outputs/output.txt"))
            .lineAggregator(new PassThroughLineAggregator<>())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when I return null in the reader, the writer is still working and puts an empty file into the output folder. What is the solution?

You can set the `shouldDeleteIfEmpty` on the `FlatFileItemWriter` and the output file will be deleted if it is empty. More details on this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/builder/FlatFileItemWriterBuilder.html#shouldDeleteIfEmpty-boolean-

> But if the file is not valid I return null in the reader.

Returning null means the datasource is valid and is exhausted (and might be empty). For an invalid datasource, I would throw an exception and fail the step instead. Another solution is to use the `NoWorkFoundStepExecutionListener` to fail the step if no work is found. More details about this listener here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#handlingStepCompletionWhenNoInputIsFound